# Custom Route in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to setup a custom route in ASP.NET MVC 4. I want my route accessible via

http://www.mydomain.com/high-school/student/1

In an attempt to setup this route, I've added the following in RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "HSStudentProfile",
  url: "high-school/student",
  defaults: new { controller = "Students", action = "HSStudentProfile" }
);
```

**StudentsController.cs**

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult HSStudentProfile()
  {
    return View("~/Views/Shared/Course/Index.cshtml");
  }
}
```

If I visit the url mentioned above, I get a 403.14 error. If I update the route config to use

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "HSStudentProfile",
  url: "{controller}/high-school/student",
  defaults: new { controller = "Students", action = "HSStudentProfile" }
);
```

It works, however, I have to change the URL path to

http://www.mydomain.com/Students/high-school/student/1

Is there a way to do this without having to have {controller} in my RouteConfig?

Comment: Shouldn't the route be "high-school/student/{id}" ? I suspect it matches some other route instead...

Comment: My goal is to have http://www.mydomain.com/high-school/student/{id}. How do I get rid of /Students/?

Comment: Following from what Alexei said, your route doesn't define anything after "student", so if you pass something there ("/1", for example), it doesn't match the route so MVC tries to open it with the default handler, and the controller doesn't exist so it errors.

Comment: For that matter, your action method doesn't even take a parameter, so why pass it in the URL?